# How to turns a home computer and a home network a server with dns to point a domain to it

Tags: dns, ip

I have a home computer that has the port opened and a fixed network ip, for example (aaa.aaa.aa), i can access the application anywhere by this ip:port, now i need know if it is possible, how can i get the DNS from this fixed network ip to make a domain point to this.

Note: I dont want to make it just like no-ip makes, i want to make the real process to point a domain from dns to this home server.

Note2: I have a windowns home server( I need windowns because the application is in delphi that runs only in this operational system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you own a domain you need to add **A record** with domain name of your choice and ip address of your server into your domain management and configure IIS server to accept incoming connection and redirect to your Delphi application